# How to override system.mail.yml in Drupal 8?

Tags: smtp, drupal-8

I have the below code in my file: `core\modules\system\config\install\system.mail.yml`

```
interface:
 default: 'php_mail'
```

I want to change the code to:

```
interface:
 default: 'SMTPMailSystem'
```

In order to get my SMTP module to work. On changing the code in the core file my module works. Since making direct changes in core file is not good I want to know how do we override such files. I am fairly new to Drupal 8 hence couldn't get through.

Answer (score 0):

Drupal has an article on [Configuration override system](https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/api/configuration-api/configuration-override-system), which gives an overview and starter code to override configurations defined in *.yml . You can jump to "Providing overrides from modules" section right away for your case.

In short:

1. Create a module (config_example used as an example)
2. Create a config_example.services.yml, and put:

```
services:
  config_example.overrider:
    class: \Drupal\config_example\ConfigExampleOverrides
    tags:
      - {name: config.factory.override, priority: 5}
```

`config.factory.override` is the important thing here, others are up to you to change.

3. Define the class which implements `ConfigFactoryOverrideInterface`:

```php
namespace Drupal\config_example;

use Drupal\Core\Cache\CacheableMetadata;
use Drupal\Core\Config\ConfigFactoryOverrideInterface;
use Drupal\Core\Config\StorageInterface;

/**
 * Example configuration override.
 */
class ConfigExampleOverrides implements ConfigFactoryOverrideInterface {

  /**
   * {@inheritdoc}
   */
  public function loadOverrides($names) {
    $overrides = array();

    if (in_array('system.mail', $names)) { // (a)
      $overrides['system.mail'] = [
        'interface' => ['default' => 'SMTPMailSystem']
      ];
    }

    return $overrides;
  }

  /**
   * {@inheritdoc}
   */
  public function getCacheSuffix() {
    return 'ConfigExampleOverrider'; // (c)
  }

  /**
   * {@inheritdoc}
   */
  public function getCacheableMetadata($name) {
    return new CacheableMetadata();
  }

  /**
   * {@inheritdoc}
   */
  public function createConfigObject($name, $collection = StorageInterface::DEFAULT_COLLECTION) {
    return NULL;
  }

}
```

The following thing is changed to work for your case:

(a) The in_array needle is changed to `system.mail` which is the YML you wish to override. The value assigned to `$overrides['system.mail']` is changed to what you wish to be placed.